# Can someone tell me how to return to start of game?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

This is a game I coded. 
It is a word guessing game.

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

def umm():
  continue
def quit():
  master.destroy()

answer = randint(0,16)
wrong_answer = randint(0,16)
wrong_answer1 = randint(0,16)

s_list =   ["apple","book","phone","sheep","ruler","pen","eraser","knife","cement","Google","file","stapler","thermometer","box","glue","yes","no"]
hint_list = ["Fruit","Read","Technology","Animal","Measure Length","Writing","Stationary","Cut  food", "Building Material","Search Engine","Paper organizer","Binding papers together","Temperature","Storage","Attach things together","Approval","Disapproval"]
secret_word = s_list[answer]
hint = f'Hint:{hint_list[answer]}'
incorrect = s_list[wrong_answer]
incorrect1 = s_list[wrong_answer1]

master = Tk()
master.title("2 Players Guessing Game!")
master.geometry('700x900+90+90')

def random1():
   label["text"] = "Player 1 won!"

def random2():
   label["text"] = "Player 2 won!"

def random3():
   label["text"] = "Player 2 won!"

def random4():
   label["text"] = "Player 1 won!"

label = Label(master, text="2 Player Guessing Game!", font  = "Arial 14")
label2 = Label(master, text="<- P1 P2 ->", font = "Arial 14")
button = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random1)
button2 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
button3 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
button4 = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random3)
button5 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
button6 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
label4 = Label(master, text=hint, font = "Arial 14")
button7 = Button(master, text="Again?", font = "Arial 14", command = umm)
button8 = Button(master, text="Quit", font = "Arial 14", command = quit)

  label.pack()
  label2.pack()
  label4.pack()
  button.pack(side=LEFT)
  button2.pack(side=LEFT)
  button3.pack(side=LEFT)
  button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
  button5.pack(side=RIGHT)
  button6.pack(side=RIGHT)
  button7.pack()
  button8.pack()

  master.mainloop()
```

Currently, my code shows that if Player 1 clicks the correct button on his or her side, it will print Player 1 won and vice versa. Now, I added in additional buttons, "Again?" and "Quit".
I also added "continue". However, it now says continue is not properly in loop. I thought that because it is in mainloop(), this is why I can use it. But it now shows the message. Why?

Comment: You create each button at the start based on the initial values. Changing the original value does nothing. You need to recreate them each time.

Comment: Update the values of the labels and buttons when you grab new answers.

Comment: After pressed `Again?` ,what did you want to do?Did you want to show `2 Player Guessing Game!`?

Comment: just like reset the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. You could get those word by `random.choice()`,it could be more easy.
2. It is not recommended to use `from tkinter import *`.

---

> just like reset the whole code.

In your Application,reset means:change `the Player x won!` to `2 Player Guessing Game!`.And use `random.choice()` to generate a new string and show it in the button.

Code:

```
from random import choice
from tkinter import *

def generateRandomWord(): # at first I don't know you need to use index.
    secret_word.set(choice(s_list))
    hint.set(final_dict[secret_word.get()]) # use dict to get the value.
    incorrect.set(choice(s_list))
    incorrect1.set(choice(s_list))

def umm():
    label['text'] = "2 Player Guessing Game!"
    generateRandomWord()

def quit():
    master.destroy()

master = Tk()

secret_word = StringVar() # use StringVar
incorrect = StringVar()
incorrect1 = StringVar()
hint = StringVar()


s_list =   ["apple","book","phone","sheep","ruler","pen","eraser","knife","cement","Google","file","stapler","thermometer","box","glue","yes","no"]
hint_list = ["Fruit","Read","Technology","Animal","Measure Length","Writing","Stationary","Cut  food", "Building Material","Search Engine","Paper organizer","Binding papers together","Temperature","Storage","Attach things together","Approval","Disapproval"]
final_dict = dict(zip(s_list,hint_list)) # generate a dict.
generateRandomWord()
master.title("2 Players Guessing Game!")
master.geometry('700x900+90+90')

def random1():
   label["text"] = "Player 1 won!"

def random2():
   label["text"] = "Player 2 won!"

def random3():
   label["text"] = "Player 2 won!"

def random4():
   label["text"] = "Player 1 won!"

label = Label(master, text="2 Player Guessing Game!", font  = "Arial 14")
label2 = Label(master, text="<- P1 P2 ->", font = "Arial 14")
button = Button(master, textvariable=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random1) # bind textvariable
button2 = Button(master, textvariable=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
button3 = Button(master, textvariable=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
button4 = Button(master, textvariable=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random3)
button5 = Button(master, textvariable=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
button6 = Button(master, textvariable=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
label4 = Label(master, textvariable=hint, font = "Arial 14")
button7 = Button(master, text="Again?", font = "Arial 14", command = umm)
button8 = Button(master, text="Quit", font = "Arial 14", command = quit)

label.pack()
label2.pack()
label4.pack()
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
button5.pack(side=RIGHT)
button6.pack(side=RIGHT)
button7.pack()
button8.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

You also could use a `list` to save those variables,buttons and labels.That's will reduce the quantity of code.

Comment: There is still one thing to do before the code is complete: The correct answer and the hint must be the same

Comment: For that case, can I use array?

Comment: "The correct answer and the hint must be the same",So you could use the same variable instead of creating two variables.If so, you could.

Comment: Ok! I will try that out now. Thanks so much!

Comment: wait how do you make it the same variable? i forgot.

Comment: Maybe revise the `textvariable` in `label4`.Just make them have the same `textvariable`.